# Change rightBarButtonItems Title

Tags: xcode, button

How can I change the title of the buttons on my **rightbarButtonItems**?

I have multiple buttons on the right side of the navigation bar, though I can change a button's title if there is only one rightbarButton but for multiple I can't.

```
doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Done"
style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouch)];
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Edit"
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
target:self action:@selector(Edit:)];
NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doneButton,editButton,nil];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:myButtonArray];
```

I want to change the title of the **editButton** but I can't using:

```
[self.editButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Navigation Bar you need to take Tool Bar either you can use custome button with title on it . ON navigation bar you can only add two button left and right.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** firstly get bar button references

```
 NSArray *arrBarBtn = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;

if([arrBarBtn count]>0)
{
   for(UIBarButtonItem *barBtn in arrBarBtn)
   {
      //do as per your requirement.
      if(barBtn.title == @"Edit")
      {
        barBtn.title == @"Done";
      }
   }
}
```

---

change like this:

```
if(self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == @"Edit") {
//Do your stuff;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
}
else if(self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == @"Done"){
//Do your stuff;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
}
```

Comment: but I am using an array of buttons for my rightBarButtonItems, not rightBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

if(self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == @"Edit") {
..

OK, may be a pseudo code.

but for newbies, do NOT compare strings using == ...only Swift will allow it.

Use isEqualToString